# Tracking Items Quantity & Price In Shopping Cart

Tags: python, django

I have a shopping cart in a Django application. You can add and remove items from the cart.

I have finally got my logic to work. Through much trouble shooting it will add items from the cart and remove them. The price is being recalculated each time you add or remove an item from the cart.

But only on the first product in the cart. The top product in the cart readjust the price based on its quantity. The rest of the products can be increased or decreased but the cost of the total always stays the same. I am unclear if this problem is in my logic in the view or model.

[image]

Thank you,

models.py

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    order_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    payment_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    payment_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self): 
            return "%s" % (self.user)

    def remove_from_cart(self, book_id):
        book = Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)
        try:
            preexisting_order = BookOrder.objects.get(book=book, cart=self)
            if preexisting_order.quantity > 1:
                preexisting_order.quantity -= 1
                preexisting_order.save()
            else:
                preexisting_order.delete()
        except BookOrder.DoesNotExist:
            pass
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def add_to_cart(request,book_id):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=book_id)
    cart,created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, active=True)
    order,created = BookOrder.objects.get_or_create(book=book,cart=cart)
    order.quantity += 1
    order.save()
    messages.success(request, "Cart updated!")
    return redirect('cart')


def remove_from_cart(request, book_id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        try:
            book = Book.objects.get(pk = book_id)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass 
        else:
            cart = Cart.objects.get(user = request.user, active = True)
            cart.remove_from_cart(book_id)
        return redirect('cart')
    else:
        return redirect('index')

def cart(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user.id, active = True)
        orders = BookOrder.objects.filter(cart=cart)
        total = 0
        count = 0
        for order in orders:
            total += (order.book.price * order.quantity)
            count += order.quantity
            context = {
            'cart': orders,
            'total': total,
            'count': count,
            }
            return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)
        else:
            return redirect('index')
```

Comment: Your example seems to imply that you are not looping through the entire list but calling only the first element in that list. In the function cart, you use cart as a variable as well as the function name. While this is not an error, it would be better to give them different names.  Also views.py has the function cart repeated. You should fix that. Try putting debug messages in the loop `cart(request)` to ensure that contex is set correctly. You should also include your main to show how cart and the other functions are called.

Comment: One way would be to put an assertion into a try except block and print the error message before continuing on. I would probably just do a print in cart to verify that both books in the cart get picked up. I just noticed that `add_to_cart()` does not call the `cart()` function so how would it get recalculated?

Comment: I was talking about the function cart in views.py not the class Cart. I think that is one reason you should be careful not to have names that seem too much alike. Also you should fix the typo in views.h in which you have the `cart()` function twice.

Comment: Look in the second section of code (views.py) There are 4 lines which start with `def`. `add_to_cart(request)`, `remove_from_cart(request)`, `cart(request)`, and `cart(request)`. You can see it in the question as you move down through the code.

Comment: I would say that after you loop through all the requests (both add and remove)  **then** call a function `update_cart(request)` (what you currently call `cart(request)`) which will loop through the entire cart and bring it up to date. That way you do not have to recalculate every time you add or remove. This would save you the recalculation time.